# How to display multiple images with content after the page completes loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a problem on my PHP website. I have a social networking site with multiple images and contents.first I want to display only content to user and display the images after all of them  are completely loaded.i want to display loading animation  before image is completely loaded.

So I'd like to hide the image and show loading animation until it loads all the data , and when it has loaded I'd like to display image with its loaded contents.

How can I do this?

Comment: try using javascript for this! Seems like its the best and easiest way to do this.

Comment: Hint: Image elements get a [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load).

Comment: Use `$(document).ready(function() { .. });` and take a look at http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a jQuery plugin for this. Or you can creat your own image preloader:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-awesome-image-preloader--net-16575